# How to print the output of each layer of CNN model after passing an image

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I have the code for CNN model. But I need the output of each and every layer of my model and my testing image is passed after compiling the model. So is there a way that i am able to see the output of each layer of my CNN model by taking my test image as input.

```
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32,3,3, input_shape = (64,64,3),activation = 
"relu"))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
classifier.add(Convolution2D(64,3,3,activation = "relu"))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
classifier.add(Flatten())
```

My test function is this :

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
test_image = image.load_img('spot.png',target_size = (64,64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image,axis = 0)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
training_set.class_indices
if result [0][0] == 0:
    prediction = 'mango_powder'  
else:
    prediction = 'mango_spot'
print(prediction)
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a model that outputs all layers:

```
inputs = classifier.input
outputs = [classifier.layers[i].output for i in range(len(classifier.layers))]
model = Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Use this model to predict with the same inputs you would use in `classifier`:

```
all_layers_predictions = model.predict(images)
```

Here, `all_layers_predictions` will be a list with the outputs of each layer.

You might need to ignore the first layer (`i = 0`) in case the input layer is appearing in `classifier.summary()`

Comment: Sir. I did not understand "images" part of the answer that images would be a list. Could you please elaborate . I have edited my question again.

Comment: Oh... sorry, my mistake. It was certainly not meant to be `images`. Fixed.

Comment: Sorry Sir. My mistake . Your code is working correctly ! But It is giving me the output as huge array of numbers for every layer. I want an image to be my output after passing through each layer. So basically I want visual representation of an image after passing through each layer of my CNN model

Comment: There aren't images, there are exactly those matrices with "channels". You can visualize each channel if you want to by picking from the arrays: `image1_channel8_fromlayer10 = all_layers_predictions[10][1,:,:,8]`

Comment: I am unable to visualize the image , It is giving me error                :IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Comment: Well, if the size is 1, the maximum index is 0. You're probably predicting a single image.